# No specs found when looping tests on Protractor

Tags: testing, protractor, automated-tests, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm using Protractor on Selenium, MacOS and Chrome.
I'm trying to run the same test using an array of elements to provide the test data:

As I read here: [Looping on a protractor test with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634558/looping-on-a-protractor-test-with-parameters/23635357#23635357)

I was trying that solution but when I run it, my test is not even found:

```
 for(var i = 0; casos.length; i++){

            (function(cotizacion){
                it('obtener $1,230.00 de la cotizacion', function(){
                    browser.get('https://mifel-danielarias.c9users.io');
                    login(user,pass);
                    fillVidaCotizadorForm(formData);
                    //browser.sleep(5000);
                    var primaTotal = element(by.binding('vida.primaTotal'));
                    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(primaTotal),4000);
                    expect(primaTotal.getText()).toBe(cotizacion);
                });
            })(casos[i].Fallecimiento);
        }
```

Output message:

```
> [14:13:01] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at
> http://localhost:4444/wd/hub [14:13:01] I/launcher - Running 1
> instances of WebDriver Started
> 
> 
> No specs found Finished in 0.003 seconds
```

This loop is inside my describe function and if I run the test normally without any loop, it runs flawlessly.

Comment: What does your Protractor config look like?

Comment: You should not use the `it` block inside any loop.

Comment: If you are looking for Data Driven Approach. You can find the way to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221397/data-driven-testing-in-protractor

Comment: @SureshSalloju Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Pakitorocker Ur welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @OptimWorks mentioned in his comment, Data Driven Approach was exactly what I was looking for, and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221397/data-driven-testing-in-protractor) provided several good answers.

Comment: You should add some context from the link as link only answers are not considered good practice. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer